# What is the error "Exception: Page not found at myFunction(Code:97:41)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I have two scripts on Google Slides that basically create a new presentation, searching for data from a Spreadsheet. They both work just fine, but one of them returns me the message "Exception: Page not found. (Code:97:41). As this error doesn't stop the code to run, I can't identify where is its origins. I didn't find any post at internet about this error. I'd like to know what causes it, to fix and stop to show me this message (in fact is just a message, because the script finishes as I'd like to.

Thank you.

Comment: What is line 97 of your code?

Comment: I might guess that you were looping through pages and your loop count is wrong and you tried to access a page that's not there.

Comment: Share your code and we can probably help you spot the problem.

Comment: The issue is on line 97 of Code.gs, so you should at least post the function on that line. Have a read here on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get that 97 was the line with problem. With this information I could find the problem. It was missing a line from the other similar code that I define the slide where I put the links for the others slides. Even without you guys see my code, your answers were very helpfull. Thanks a lot.

Just for curiosity, I post to you guys this part of my code.

```
    slides = presentation.getSlides(); //this line was missing
    slides[0].selectAsCurrentPage(); //also this one

    var int;
    table = slides[0].getTables()[0];
    i = 1;
    for (row = 7; row < 25; row++) {
         for (column = 1; column < 7; column++) {

            cell = table.getCell(row, column);

            if (cell.getText() != "") {
               int = Math.ceil(Number(cell.getText().asString())/4);
               if (int > 0) {
                  var itens = slides[i].getShapes() //this is the line 97
                  var slideID = i;
                  cell.getText().getTextStyle().setLinkSlide(slideID);
                  i = i + int;
               }
            }
         }
    }
    slideID = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common error:

`var values=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();`

The correct version is:

`var values=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();`

The third parameter is the number of rows